# how to convert sql query to sqlalchemy in python fatsapi

Tags: fastapi

SELECT *
FROM order_trade join credential  as buyer on
buyer.user_id = order_trade.buyer_id
join credential  as seller on
seller.user_id = order_trade.seller_id;

Comment: Are you using SQLALchemy ORM or plain SQLAlchemy? What have you tried, and how did the result differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

as ORM go for

```
session.query(order_trade).filter(order_trade.buyer_id=buyer.user_id).first()
```

or plain query

```
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM order_trade as ot,buyer as b where order_trade.buyer.id = b.user_id") # this is simple query
```